# Asset Compressor Laravel bundle doesn't minify JS

Tags: php, laravel, bundle, assets, minify

The Asset Compressor bundle in Laravel minifies my css files perfectly, but gives me an empty file for my Javascript.
I first thought it had to do with Java not being installed properly on my server, but i re-installed and its still gives me an empty .js file.

Answer (score -1):

not to be mean, rude, or anything else, but since when java has something to do with javascript ( .js ) files ?

Comment: Because AssetCompressor uses Google's closure.jar for compilation, see https://github.com/Vespakoen/AssetCompressor/tree/master/drivers/closure-compiler. I can't comment on this matter since it out of my knowledge.

Comment: based off Google Compiler, which uses JRE